# Is numeric animation behaviour possible with knockout observable?

Tags: javascript, animation, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

For example you have simple model like this:

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
    var timer,
        self = this;
        
    this.value = ko.observable(10);
    this.value2 = ko.observable(10);

    this.value.subscribe(function(newValue){
        clearInterval(timer)
        timer = setInterval(function(){
           if (self.value2() == newValue) {
              clearInterval(timer);
              return;
           }
           
           self.value2(self.value2() + 1);
        }, 100);
    });    

    
    this.update = function(){
        this.value(this.value() + 10);
    };
};
 
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
body { font-family: arial; font-size: 14px; }
.liveExample { padding: 1em; background-color: #EEEEDD; border: 1px solid #CCC; max-width: 655px; }
.liveExample input { font-family: Arial; }
.liveExample b { font-weight: bold; }
.liveExample p { margin-top: 0.9em; margin-bottom: 0.9em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class='liveExample'>   
    <p>Value: <input data-bind='value: value' /></p> 
    <p>Animated value: <input data-bind='value: value2' /></p> 
    <button data-bind="click: update">
    +10
    </button>
</div>
```

Each time you press button `value` would be incremented and `value2` would be animatied with numeric animation (like in Qt QML for example). In this sample this done throw new variable and self made timer.

### Question

Is here is any way in knockout to do such behaviour with custom binding or custom extender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've sketched custom "animatedValue" binding, hope it helps:

```
function createValueAccessor(val) {
  var displayValue = ko.observable(val());
  var timer;
  val.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    clearInterval(timer)
    timer = setInterval(function(){
      if(displayValue() == newValue) {
        clearInterval(timer);
      } else {
        displayValue(displayValue() + 1);
      }
    }, 100);
  });    
  return function() {
    return displayValue;
  }
}

// Binding handler

ko.bindingHandlers.animatedValue = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, createValueAccessor(value), allBindingsAccessor, viewModel);
    }
};
```

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
    var timer,
        self = this;
        
    this.value = ko.observable(10);
    this.value2 = ko.observable(10);

    this.value.subscribe(function(newValue){
        clearInterval(timer)
        timer = setInterval(function(){
           if (self.value2() == newValue) {
              clearInterval(timer);
              return;
           }
           
           self.value2(self.value2() + 1);
        }, 100);
    });    

    
    this.update = function(){
        this.value(this.value() + 10);
    };
};
 
function createValueAccessor(val) {
  var displayValue = ko.observable(val());
  var timer;
  val.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    clearInterval(timer)
    timer = setInterval(function(){
      if(displayValue() == newValue) {
        clearInterval(timer);
      } else {
        displayValue(displayValue() + 1);
      }
    }, 100);
  });    
  return function() {
    return displayValue;
  }
}

// Binding handler

ko.bindingHandlers.animatedValue = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, createValueAccessor(value), allBindingsAccessor, viewModel);
    }
};

ko.bindingHandlers.animatedText = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var displayValue = ko.observable(value());
        var timer;
        value.subscribe(function(newValue) {
          clearInterval(timer)
            timer = setInterval(function() {
              if(displayValue() == newValue) {
                clearInterval(timer);
              } else {
                displayValue(displayValue() + 1);
                ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function() { return displayValue; });
              }
            }, 100);
        });    
      ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function() { return displayValue; });
    }
};


ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
body { font-family: arial; font-size: 14px; }
.liveExample { padding: 1em; background-color: #EEEEDD; border: 1px solid #CCC; max-width: 655px; }
.liveExample input { font-family: Arial; }
.liveExample b { font-weight: bold; }
.liveExample p { margin-top: 0.9em; margin-bottom: 0.9em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class='liveExample'>   
    <p>Value: <input data-bind='value: value' /></p> 
    <p>Animated value: <input data-bind='value: value2' /></p> 
    <p>Animated value via animatedText binding: <span data-bind='animatedText: value'></span></p> 
    <p>Animated value via binding: <input data-bind='animatedValue: value' /></p>
    <button data-bind="click: update">
    +10
    </button>
</div>
```

#### Update 1

I've added "animatedText" custom binding handler.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.animatedText = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var displayValue = ko.observable(value());
        var timer;
        value.subscribe(function(newValue) {
          clearInterval(timer)
            timer = setInterval(function() {
              if(displayValue() == newValue) {
                clearInterval(timer);
              } else {
                displayValue(displayValue() + 1);
                ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function() { return displayValue; });
              }
            }, 100);
        });    
      ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function() { return displayValue; });
    }
};
```

Comment: Hm. This works with `value` bindingHandler but do not work with `text`. May be you know why?

Comment: Sure, I've overloaded "value" binding (by using "ko.bindingHandlers.value.init" and "ko.bindingHandlers.value.update") because of original sample was using it. And I've called a new binding "animatedValue". I guess you can override the "text" binding the same way.

Comment: It wasn't so easy as I thought. I've updated the answer with new "animatedText" binding.